# getting error "c3" is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, c3.js

I'm trying to write a custom bar chart directive in angular js using ES6. I have installed the c3 library using bower install c3 --save. when I run gulp serve I'm getting the error "c3" is not defined  no-undef. Below is my code -

```
 export class MyDirective {    
 constructor($interval) {
    'ngInject';
     this.template = '<div id=chart></div>';
     this.restrict = 'E';
    this.scope = {}
    this.$interval = $interval;
}

compile(tElement) {
    tElement.css('position', 'absolute');
}

link(scope, element) {
    this.$interval(() => this.chart(), 1000);
}

chart() {
    c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data:{
            columns: [
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
            ],
            type: 'bar'
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
            }
            // or
            //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
        }    
    });        
}
 }
```

Comment: bower install will only download the appropriate files to your project folder, but you still have to include the scripts and css files in your index.html. Depending on your project environment, you may well help a gulp task that does this...

Comment: The gulp task is including the c3.js and its dependent d3.js file.

Answer (score 1):

If you install c3 directly, it will not be "angular friendly". I use c3 in my project with es2015 (and a babel transpire) and I choose to use [c3-angular](https://github.com/jettro/c3-angular-directive)

To install it:

```
bower install c3-angular --save
```

And to import it as a dependency :

```
import 'c3-angular';
let barChartModule = angular.module('barChart', ['gridshore.c3js.chart']);
```

If you do this, you can define charts in your view this it is explained in the [examples here](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/#getstarted)

Comment: Fixed the error by adding "c3":true in "globals": { "c3":true} in .eslintrc file.